Syntax on accessing authorization header of an API request in node
 const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
Apologies if this question may seem basic, but I am curious why we use ["authorization"] and not just .authorization
I did some research and found that it had to do with the lower/upper casing, but the answers I found were not clicking well with me. I was wondering if someone had a better explanation.

You can use just .authorization in this case, it's the same as doing ["authorization"]

Appreciate your question.
The short answer to the question is :  Javascript objects are associative arrays.
Therefore it can be accessed in two forms - by array notation as well as by dot notation. This answer may necessitate some basics about associative arrays. Please see below some codes.
An ordinary array in Javascript.
const somearray = []
somearray[0] = 1
somearray[1] = 2
somearray[2] = 3

// accessed through array notation
console.log(somearray[0]);  // 1
// ..
console.log(somearray[2]);  // 2

// However the same array cannot be accessed through dot notation.
console.log(somearray.0);  // error
..
console.log(somearray.2);  // error

Let us see another array.
const associativearray = [ ]
associativearray[‘a’] = 1  
associativearray[‘b’] = 2
associativearray[‘c’] = 3

// accessed by array notation
console.log(associativearray[‘a’]); // 1
// …
console.log(associativearray[‘c’]); // 3

// The same array can be also be accessed by object notation. 
console.log(associativearray.a); // 1
//  …
console.log(associativearray.c); // 3

Such type of arrays accessed in the two forms are called associative arrays.
Now we have got the distinction between an ordinary array and an associative array. An associative array will have only non-numeric string indexes while an ordinary array will have only numeric indexes.
Coming back to the answer, Javascript objects are associative arrays , therefore it can be accessed in the following two forms.
const obj = { a : 1, b : 2, c: 3 }

// accessed by object notation
console.log(obj.a) // 1   
// accessed by array notation
console.log(obj[‘a’]) // 1
// ..

console.log(obj.c) // 3
console.log(obj[‘c’]) // 3

It may be more clarified by now. Please comment if any clarifications may be required.
Citation:
Associative array
